# Deriving a formula for the pressure exerted on a container wall due to a single particle colliding on it/bouncing off it

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, collision, ideal-gas

I am writing a python script to simulate ideal gas particles in a circular container (in 2 dimensions only).

One thing I need to do is add code to calculate the pressure on the container due to a single particle bouncing off it. For ease, the particle has a radius of 1 and a mass of 1. I can implement the code once I know a formula, however I am struggling to come up with/find a formula. Here is my thought process so far (for a particle just constrained to moving along the x-axis, my actual code does account for velocities with an x and y component).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

I don't know what dt is supposed to be? Is  that the time taken for the particle to hit the container wall after starting from its initial position? And then how would I account for the area? It is a circular container in 2 dimensions, so does using the area even make sense?

Thanks in advance,
Sid

Comment: think of the $dt$ as a $\Delta t$, which is where the last line comes from.  $\Delta p $ = $p(t_2) - p(t_1)$ = $ m( v_2 - v_1 ) = 2mv $

Comment: But what actually is Δt ? Is it the time between the initial position of the ball and the point at which it collides? Or is it how long it takes for the collision, i.e. the time from the instant it collides with the wall, to the instant in which it bounces back (is that not instantaneous?)

Comment: You have computed an impulse. That's an invariant in this problem, but the force during a collision is generally time-dependent, and it's the integral of the force function over the time interval of the collision that gives you the impulse. You can set the time interval depending on the collision model, which you also get to choose. In a dynamic simulation, the programmer usually chooses the time interval for stepping through the simulation.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.sciwebhop.net/sci_web/physics/a-level/as_module2/derivation_of_pv.htm   This formula gives the average pressure so might be what you are looking for, the link derives it for a cube but it applies to any 3D space. As you are looking at a 2D area you want to replace the 1/3 with a 1/2, or for 1D just ignore the 1/3. Note that an ideal gas assumes that the radius of a particle is negligible so you do not need to include that in the calculation.